# Doctrine 2: JOIN query not working

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, entity

The query below is not giving any result.

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery("            
                SELECT cs, cc 
                FROM App\Entity\Continents cs 
                JOIN cs.countries cc 
                WHERE cs.enabled = 1 AND cs.deleted = 0
              ");
```

If I print the query using "print_r($query);" it prints the object... but if I try to get the sql using "print($query->getSQL());" it doesn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Please note: it works fine without the join.

**The entity mapping**

**Countries Entity**

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Continents")
 * @Table(name="countries")
 */
class Countries {

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Continents", inversedBy="countries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="continent_id")
*/
protected $continents;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $continent_id;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $iso_number;

/** @Column(type="string", length=2) */
protected $iso_2_code;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $iso_3_code;

/** @Column(type="string", length=45) */
protected $name;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $default_currency;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $currency_symbol;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=3) */
protected $currency_id;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $postcode_check;

/** @Column(type="string", length=150) */
protected $postcode_regex;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $enabled;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $deleted;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $created;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $created_by;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $modified;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $modified_by;

public function __construct() {

}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getContinents() {
    return $this->continents;
}

public function setContinents(\App\Entity\Continents $continents) {
    $this->continents = $continents;
}

public function getContinent_id() {
    return $this->continent_id;
}

public function setContinent_id($continent_id) {
    $this->continent_id = $continent_id;
}

public function getIso_number() {
    return $this->iso_number;
}

public function setIso_number($iso_number) {
    $this->iso_number = $iso_number;
}

public function getIso_2_code() {
    return $this->iso_2_code;
}

public function setIso_2_code($iso_2_code) {
    $this->iso_2_code = $iso_2_code;
}

public function getIso_3_code() {
    return $this->iso_3_code;
}

public function setIso_3_code($iso_3_code) {
    $this->iso_3_code = $iso_3_code;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getDefault_currency() {
    return $this->default_currency;
}

public function setDefault_currency($default_currency) {
    $this->default_currency = $default_currency;
}

public function getCurrency_symbol() {
    return $this->currency_symbol;
}

public function setCurrency_symbol($currency_symbol) {
    $this->currency_symbol = $currency_symbol;
}

public function getCurrency_id() {
    return $this->currency_id;
}

public function setCurrency_id($currency_id) {
    $this->currency_id = $currency_id;
}

public function getPostcode_check() {
    return $this->postcode_check;
}

public function setPostcode_check($postcode_check) {
    $this->postcode_check = $postcode_check;
}

public function getPostcode_regex() {
    return $this->postcode_regex;
}

public function setPostcode_regex($postcode_regex) {
    $this->postcode_regex = $postcode_regex;
}

public function getEnabled() {
    return $this->enabled;
}

public function setEnabled($enabled) {
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

public function getDeleted() {
    return $this->deleted;
}

public function setDeleted($deleted) {
    $this->deleted = $deleted;
}

public function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
}

public function setCreated($created) {
    $this->created = $created;
}

public function getModified() {
    return $this->modified;
}

public function setModified($modified) {
    $this->modified = $modified;
}

public function getCreated_by() {
    return $this->created_by;
}

public function setCreated_by($created_by) {
    $this->created_by = $created_by;
}

public function getModified_by() {
    return $this->modified_by;
}

public function setModified_by($modified_by) {
    $this->modified_by = $modified_by;
}
```

}

**Continents Entity**

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="continents")
 */
class Continents {

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Countries", mappedBy="continents")
*/
protected $countries;

/** @Column(type="string", length=7) */
protected $name;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $enabled;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $deleted;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $created;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $created_by;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $modified;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $modified_by;

public function __construct() {
    $this->countries = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getCountries() {
    return $this->countries;
}

public function setCountries($countries) {
    $this->countries = $countries;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getCreated_by() {
    return $this->created_by;
}

public function setCreated_by($created_by) {
    $this->created_by = $created_by;
}

public function getModified_by() {
    return $this->modified_by;
}

public function setModified_by($modified_by) {
    $this->modified_by = $modified_by;
}

public function getEnabled() {
    return $this->enabled;
}

public function setEnabled($enabled) {
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

public function getDeleted() {
    return $this->deleted;
}

public function setDeleted($deleted) {
    $this->deleted = $deleted;
}

public function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
}

public function setCreated($created) {
    $this->created = $created;
}

public function getModified() {
    return $this->modified;
}

public function setModified($modified) {
    $this->modified = $modified;
}
```

}

Comment: Don't forget to use the `ON` clause when you use `JOIN`.

Comment: Do I need the ON clause after doing the mapping? @Edper

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what this column name you have but you should escape it by backticks like that:

```
   SELECT cs.* , cc.*          -- //--you are selecting tables.
   FROM `Continents` cs   --escape by backticks here
   JOIN countries cc    --no need cs here
   ON  ............       --condition here (relation between the two tables)
   WHERE cs.enabled = 1 AND cs.deleted = 0  --this is good
```

Comment: I have two tables 'Continents' and 'Countries' linked together using doctrines ONE-to-Many associations (One continent has many countries). I am retrieving all columns in the both tables.

Comment: A similar query below works without an 'ON CLAUSE'

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
                        SELECT sa, sc 
                        FROM App\Entity\Studyabroadcourses sa 
                        JOIN sa.studyabroadschools sc 
                        WHERE sa.coursename LIKE :searchTerm AND sa.enabled = 1 AND sa.deleted = 0
                    ")
                    ->setParameters(array(
                        'searchTerm' => '%' . $searchTerm . '%'
                    ));

Comment: The association below should take care of mapping

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Continents", inversedBy="countries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="continent_id")
    */
    protected $continents;

Comment: /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Countries", mappedBy="continents")
    */
    protected $countries;

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. The problem was in my Entities. I updated my continents and countries entities as below and it worked fine. I hope this will help someone else.

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Continents")
 * @Table(name="continents")
 */
class Continents {

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Countries", mappedBy="continents")
*/
protected $countries;

/** @Column(type="string", length=7) */
protected $name;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $enabled;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $deleted;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $created;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $created_by;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $modified;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $modified_by;

public function __construct() {
    $this->countries = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getCountries() {
    return $this->countries;
}

public function setCountries($countries) {
    $this->countries = $countries;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getCreated_by() {
    return $this->created_by;
}

public function setCreated_by($created_by) {
    $this->created_by = $created_by;
}

public function getModified_by() {
    return $this->modified_by;
}

public function setModified_by($modified_by) {
    $this->modified_by = $modified_by;
}

public function getEnabled() {
    return $this->enabled;
}

public function setEnabled($enabled) {
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

public function getDeleted() {
    return $this->deleted;
}

public function setDeleted($deleted) {
    $this->deleted = $deleted;
}

public function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
}

public function setCreated($created) {
    $this->created = $created;
}

public function getModified() {
    return $this->modified;
}

public function setModified($modified) {
    $this->modified = $modified;
}
```

}

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Continents")
 * @Table(name="countries")
 */
class Countries {

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Continents", inversedBy="countries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="continent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $continents;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $continent_id;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $iso_number;

/** @Column(type="string", length=2) */
protected $iso_2_code;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $iso_3_code;

/** @Column(type="string", length=45) */
protected $name;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $default_currency;

/** @Column(type="string", length=3) */
protected $currency_symbol;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=3) */
protected $currency_id;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $postcode_check;

/** @Column(type="string", length=150) */
protected $postcode_regex;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $enabled;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=1) */
protected $deleted;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $created;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $created_by;

/** @Column(type="datetime") */
protected $modified;

/** @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
protected $modified_by;

public function __construct() {

}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getContinents() {
    return $this->continents;
}

public function setContinents(\App\Entity\Continents $continents) {
    $this->continents = $continents;
}

public function getContinent_id() {
    return $this->continent_id;
}

public function setContinent_id($continent_id) {
    $this->continent_id = $continent_id;
}

public function getIso_number() {
    return $this->iso_number;
}

public function setIso_number($iso_number) {
    $this->iso_number = $iso_number;
}

public function getIso_2_code() {
    return $this->iso_2_code;
}

public function setIso_2_code($iso_2_code) {
    $this->iso_2_code = $iso_2_code;
}

public function getIso_3_code() {
    return $this->iso_3_code;
}

public function setIso_3_code($iso_3_code) {
    $this->iso_3_code = $iso_3_code;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getDefault_currency() {
    return $this->default_currency;
}

public function setDefault_currency($default_currency) {
    $this->default_currency = $default_currency;
}

public function getCurrency_symbol() {
    return $this->currency_symbol;
}

public function setCurrency_symbol($currency_symbol) {
    $this->currency_symbol = $currency_symbol;
}

public function getCurrency_id() {
    return $this->currency_id;
}

public function setCurrency_id($currency_id) {
    $this->currency_id = $currency_id;
}

public function getPostcode_check() {
    return $this->postcode_check;
}

public function setPostcode_check($postcode_check) {
    $this->postcode_check = $postcode_check;
}

public function getPostcode_regex() {
    return $this->postcode_regex;
}

public function setPostcode_regex($postcode_regex) {
    $this->postcode_regex = $postcode_regex;
}

public function getEnabled() {
    return $this->enabled;
}

public function setEnabled($enabled) {
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

public function getDeleted() {
    return $this->deleted;
}

public function setDeleted($deleted) {
    $this->deleted = $deleted;
}

public function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
}

public function setCreated($created) {
    $this->created = $created;
}

public function getModified() {
    return $this->modified;
}

public function setModified($modified) {
    $this->modified = $modified;
}

public function getCreated_by() {
    return $this->created_by;
}

public function setCreated_by($created_by) {
    $this->created_by = $created_by;
}

public function getModified_by() {
    return $this->modified_by;
}

public function setModified_by($modified_by) {
    $this->modified_by = $modified_by;
}
```

}